# Adding multiple lines of body in script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently using the following code in a spreadsheet to send emails.

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
In the above the message is only being processed from a single cell while i want it to use multiple cells.
```

Example: 
[the second column contains the body to be sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlCLV.jpg)

how can i tweak the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should explain more about your problem, what you've already try/done et try to be more specific. Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm guessing a bit here but you can do something like this `if(dataA.Greeting && dataA.FirstName && dataA.Close){var message=dataA.Greeting + ' ' + dataA.FirstName + ',\n ' + dataA.Body + '\n\n' + dataA.Close;}`

Answer (score 2):

Put the message in a single cell and format it as you wish within that cell. i.e. if you want to skip down a line or 2 hold control and press return and the cursor will go to the next line. 
[image]

Get the cell in the script.
[image]

When you send the email the formatting will be retained.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use '\n\n'on the script message to jump rows.